# How to create a debian package from a bash script and a systemd service?

Tags: debian, systemd, packaging

How to build a debian package from a bash script and a systemd service?

The systemd service will control the script by starting/stoping ready to use after the `.deb` will be installed successfully. From a web searching there are some easy exemples to convert only a single file (python, shell , ruby ... script) to `.deb`.

Comment: Try [`dpkg-deb`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg/dpkg-deb.1.en.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here’s a minimal source package which will install a shell script and an associated service.

The tree is as follows:

```
minpackage
├── debian
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── control
│   ├── install
│   ├── minpackage.service
│   ├── rules
│   └── source
│       └── format
└── script
```

`script` is your script, with permissions 755; `debian/minpackage.service` is your service.

`debian/changelog` needs to look something like

```
minpackage (1.0) unstable; urgency=medium                     
                                                                
  * Initial release.                                            
                                                                
 -- GAD3R <gad3r@example.org>  Tue, 05 Jan 2021 21:08:35 +0100
```

`debian/control` should contain

```
Source: minpackage                         
Section: admin                             
Priority: optional                         
Maintainer: GAD3R <gad3r@example.org>
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13)     
Standards-Version: 4.5.1                   
Rules-Requires-Root: no                    
                                           
Package: minpackage                        
Architecture: all                          
Depends: ${misc:Depends}                   
Description: My super package
```

`debian/rules` should contain

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f  
                    
%:                  
        dh $@
```

(with a real <kbd>Tab</kbd> before `dh`).

The remaining files can be created as follows:

```
mkdir -p debian/source
echo "3.0 (native)" > debian/source/format
echo script usr/bin > debian/install
```

To build the package, run

```
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

in the `minpackage` directory.

This will create `minpackage_1.0_all.deb` in the parent directory. It will also take care of the systemd maintainer scripts for you, so the service will automatically be enabled when the package is installed, and support the various override mechanisms available in Debian.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.  I didn't have the `debian/*` files handy off the top of my head, so the binary package to me was simpler to write up.

Comment: I do this often enough that I know the minimum structure off by heart ;-). I just use `dch --create` for `debian/changelog` to get the timestamp and spacing right.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to deploy `myservice.service` and `myscript` you want a tree structure like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── control
│   ├── postinst
│   ├── postrm
│   └── prerm
├── lib
│   └── systemd
│       └── system
│           └── myservice.service
└── usr
    └── bin
        └── myscript
```

`./DEBIAN/` should contain the [control files](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg-dev/deb-control.5.en.html) and maintainer scripts used for metadata and deploying.

Here's a basic control file:

```
Package: mypackage
Version: 0.1
Architecture: all
Maintainer: GAD3R <gad3r@unix.stackexchange.com>
Description: This is my package!
```

[dh_installsystemd(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html) is normally used to add default code to the maintainer scripts to manage the services.  Yours would probably look like this:

postinst:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.2
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        # This will only remove masks created by d-s-h on package removal.
        deb-systemd-helper unmask 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true

        # was-enabled defaults to true, so new installations run enable.
        if deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled 'myservice.service'; then
                # Enables the unit on first installation, creates new
                # symlinks on upgrades if the unit file has changed.
                deb-systemd-helper enable 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
        else
                # Update the statefile to add new symlinks (if any), which need to be
                # cleaned up on purge. Also remove old symlinks.
                deb-systemd-helper update-state 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.2
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
                systemctl --system daemon-reload >/dev/null || true
                if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                        _dh_action=restart
                else
                        _dh_action=start
                fi
                deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
```

postrm:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.2
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
        systemctl --system daemon-reload >/dev/null || true
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.2
if [ "$1" = "remove" ]; then
        if [ -x "/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper" ]; then
                deb-systemd-helper mask 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi

if [ "$1" = "purge" ]; then
        if [ -x "/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper" ]; then
                deb-systemd-helper purge 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
                deb-systemd-helper unmask 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
```

prerm:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.2
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ] && [ "$1" = remove ]; then
        deb-systemd-invoke stop 'myservice.service' >/dev/null || true
fi
# End automatically added section
```

Then put it all togeather with:

```
dpkg-deb -b . mypackage.deb
```

Comment: The maintainer scripts for systemd are quite a bit more complex than `systemctl enable` etc. See `/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst` for an example. As you say, they are usually generated by `dh_installsystemd`, but that only works for source packages, not binary packages as you show here.

Comment: While you were typing that I found some of the boilercode from `dh_installsystemd` to help OP out.  You are entirely correct.  Perhaps `dh_make` would make a better answer.

Comment: Even `dh_make` is overkill here IMO ;-). It would leave a lot of boilerplate to remove...