# Installing the deb package as Service in Debian

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian, scripting, services

I have a Deb package with set of binaries(.NET 6 based), but these application we need to install as a Service in Debian machine.

I can able to do the service installation manually., Need some input how to make a Deb Package with service bash script in it.

Below is my script for your reference. Any input would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#IEC Service 
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/ProtocolService
[Unit] 
Description=Protocol Service Provider 
[Service] 
WorkingDirectory= /home/debian/publish/ServiceProvider 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/debian/publish/ServiceProvider.dll 
Restart=always 
RestartSec=10 # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes 
SyslogIdentifier=offershare-web-app 
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 
[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
#start the service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable service_name 
sudo systemctl start service_name
```

Comment: I don't see any `deb` package in your systemd service (also the bash script you provided will fail, but I assume you are not actually using that script...). In the line: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/debian/publish/ServiceProvider.dll` I don't see any deb package, so I cannot understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Regarding: *"I can able to do the service installation manually"*, what are the commands you use for the service installation?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627703/86440) help at all?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use [debhelper](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debhelper/debhelper.7.en.html)'s [`dh_installsystemd`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html), [`dh_systemd_enable`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debhelper/dh_systemd_enable.1.en.html) and [`dh_systemd_start`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debhelper/dh_systemd_start.1.en.html).

To use these, all you need to do is ensure your service file exists as `debian/<package>.service`, then add the following line to your maintainer scripts (`debian/{post,pre}{inst,rm}`).

```
#DEBHELPER#
```

This line will be replaced with Debian's current service policy which will enable/start services, handle upgrades, and (un)masking of services.  It will also be sure to respect user's global configuration (in case they don't want services enabled by default).

Then simply build your package as normal (`dpkg-buildpackage` or `debuild`).  Your service will be installed to the correct location, and some [helper commands](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/init-system-helpers/deb-systemd-helper.1p.en.html) which call `start/enable/unmask/stop/disable...` actions will be automatically added to your maintainer scripts and installed.

Further reading:

- [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)

---

If you're not using `debhelper` (perhaps you are using `dpkg-deb`, `cpack`, or packing it yourself with `ar`), then add `systemctl enable` and `systemctl start` to `postinst` and `systemctl disable` and `systemctl stop` to `prerm`.  Some global settings and edge cases are not covered this way, but it will mostly work.